# Woocommerce checkout Internal Server Error on checkout if added custome field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a costume field as a tax in the woo commerce indeed it is showing up in cart as expected and in checkout also but when i proceed to payment or checkout it says `Internal Server Error`

> [09-Jun-2017 17:44:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   get_id() on array in
>   /home/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx.com/test/wp-content/plug‌​ins/woocommerce-pdf-‌​invoices/includes/ab‌​stracts/abstract-inv‌​oice.php
>   on line 615

my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    $percentage = 0.03;
    $taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->taxes);
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total + $taxes ) * $percentage;   
    // Make sure that you return false here.  We can't double tax people!
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Processing Fee', $surcharge, false, '' );

}
```

Comment: Not because of this - may be some other reason

Comment: @MujeebuRahman i dint get you this is my demo site `http://invinseo.com/test` i vl add the code can u check plz its happening if i add it

Comment: Check the error log

Comment: `[09-Jun-2017 17:44:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_id() on array in /home/certjhqy/public_html/invinseo.com/test/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices/includes/abstracts/abstract-invoice.php on line 615`

Comment: Its only warning. Any other errors?

Comment: update the comment for errror

Comment: disable pdf invoice plugin and check

Comment: thanks for the reply silly error worked thanks for the response much appreciated

Comment: i have a small question i feel u can help me out will u be able to help me if u dont mind ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146292/discussion-between-shaik-and-mujeebu-rahman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call to a member function `get_id()` on array is coming from woocommerce-pdf-‌​invoices plugin. Disabling it will resolve this error